# display fragment in a different container, depending on orientation

Tags: android, fragment, illegalstateexception

My activity has 2 different xml layout for portrait and landscape. I'm trying to use the same fragment when orientation change, with that code in Activity's onCreate() :

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
    frag = Fragment
        .instantiate(this, PlayerControlsFragment.class.getName());
} else {
    frag = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag(FRAG_TAG);
}
```

then, depending on orientation :

```
private void initLandscapePlayerFragment(FragmentTransaction ft) {
    ft.add(R.id.layout_center_top, frag);
}
private void initPortraitPlayerFragment(FragmentTransaction ft) {
    ft.add(R.id.layout_left_top, frag);
}
```

and it gives me a nice

> IllegalStateException: Can't change container ID of fragment Frag

Indeed, when I use the same container id in both xml, it works, but it's not a solution in my case.
I've tried different random solutions (detach before destroying activity, etc.) without success..
Any idea ?

Comment: Why do you need different ids for the container?

Comment: well, my layout structure is completely different whether I'm in portrait or landscape orientation...

Comment: and as portrait mode use only one container for all my fragments (switched by actionbar navigation tabs), I cannot use the same container IDs in both mode (landscape display all 3 fragments in 3 containers)

Comment: I see. Then, perhaps do something similar to the canonical Shakespare fragment example and use separate activities for these cases like they use one activity for small screens and another for tablets with a main activity to control.

Comment: actually they does not seem to use different activity, and definitely not 2 different navigation modes..

Comment: See this figure http://developer.android.com/images/fundamentals/fragments.png - that shows how they use one activity with two fragments for tablets and two activities with the same fragments for smaller screens.

Comment: @andyandy that diagram is what we are trying to do, but specifically with respect to rotation. The diagram shows accommodating different screen widths but not how to handle the fragments if the device changes screen width during the lifecycle (orientation).

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else reading. Please understand what we are attempting to do. We are not simply handling a screen rotation. **We are attempting to reattach a fragment after a screen rotation *and a layout change*.**

Android throws an error about not attaching the fragment back to a container with the same ID. The problem is that with a layout change, the container doesn't exist, we specifically want to attach to a new container (because it's a different layout ie.landscape with multiple panels).

I'm probably just as frustrated as yourself. I've found there is no solution for your answer, it's not possible from what I can tell. It's simply not possible to setRetainInstance(true) on a UI fragment and reattach after screen rotation. At least not using the support library anyway (native support might work, I don't know/ irrelevant).

In the end, I just allow the the fragments to be dumped and recreate from scratch.

It can be a hassle because the backstack is still there..

I had to call

```
super.onCreate(null)
```

dumping the fragment transaction backstack.

Then using my own information in the bundle from onSaveStateInsance to recreate the screen in line with users expectation of the layout change (which of the two fragments would now occupy the whole screen).

The behaviour was highly application specific... so I'm happy to ellaborate or discuss how it applies to you, but essentially to reiterate, I had to dump everything and recrate from scratch inline with user expectations, nothing came automatically from android. In fact android got in the way with a backstack that would only crash and with no way to kill the backstack but to pass null to the super.oncreate call.

Comment: It would be great to get an explanation for the downvote, if you know a better solution, that would be awesome. The above answer does work though.

Answer (score 0):

I have to solve this problem as well. In my case I'm using the "add" method the first time that I add the fragment to the container and "deattach" to remove the fragment. In theory the advantage of "deattach" is that when you use later "attach", the fragment goes automatically to the previous container.

This approach works fine until the user rotate the device and change the containers, in this case if the container is not present on the screen you will get a black screen.

It would be great to have the possibility to change the container before call the attach method but apparently this is not possible... In other thread I have got some ideas like replicate the fragments before add them to the screen using the new container

[Android Fragment - move from one View to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826585/android-fragment-move-from-one-view-to-another)

Any other ideas?

Answer (score -2):

from reading the design documentation on [supporting multiple screens (#Using configuration qualifiers)](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#qualifiers)  you should not be taking control over which layout is used to inflate the view depending on your device orientation. The correct approach is to add the landscape version of the view to the \*-land resource folder. Simplify your code by handing over the control of which resource is selected to Android and delete those private init methods you have. Do you still have the same problem?

Comment: yes, I have one main.xml in /res/layout, and the other in /res/layout-land (and I will have one in /res/layout-xlarge-land), but those are completely different :  
1- the portrait one contains only one container, and the 3 fragments are switched using actionbar navigation tabs.
2 the landscape one contains 3 containers, one for each fragment . 
Any recommandation for that particular scenario ?

Comment: I see what you are saying... I have also entertained this line of thought but I did not need to implement it since my requirement for tabs was born out of screen real-estate therefore the smaller screen devices had tabs and the larger screens did not, no mixing and matching as in your case. Is there a reason why you are adding the fragment in code? Could you declare it in XML therefore relinquishing responsibility of what is the root container id? My understanding of the error message you are seeing is that the FragManager is unhappy you are changing the only thing it can identify frags by.

Comment: well, I guess the fragmentManager could also identify them by tag... and it's unhappy even if I detach the fragments before the activity is destroyed ! I originally add the fragments from the code because it first seemed more flexible, because I also have a fragment that does not have a layout, because the mix of code-added/fixed ones generates issues, and because the use of actionbar navigation tab seems to be designed for this way of doing... I may think about using those tabs to hide/show fragment layout though, if there is no other solution... pretty disappointing !

Comment: His question didn't imply he wasn't doing it correctly. The issue is that the retained fragments can't be reattached to the new layout.

Comment: I don't think that merits a down vote. Unless, you have something to add @Pork? Subverting the OS's selection strategy is always going to end you in trouble. The solution is to not subvert the Os's res selection policy.

Comment: Because from what I can see, you've misunderstood the question. 

The problem is how can he retain the fragment prior to the rotation and then add it to the new activity?

So it's a problem that is encountered when using the standard approach. I personally am having this problem and found this answer to be a distraction.