# how to move from one fragment to another fragment on button click

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using the SherlockFragments library for the sliding menu.I have list of items as menu when
 I click on item fragment get opened as an activity but it is a fragment.Now I am new to fragments.i don't know how to move from one fragment to another fragment.As in activity, we have intent to move to another activity.but in fragment I don't how to move to another fragment.I have a button in fragmentA.when I click on this button it moves to fragment B.
 By googling I came to know that it has different cycles but anyhow I get toast msg when I click button
  here is following code

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.actionnetworklogin, container, false);
        Button login = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.login);

        login.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext().getApplicationContext(),"login clicked", 5000).show();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }   
}
```

Can someone please tell me how can I move one fragment to another fragment?

Is there any other method that I can use activities instead of fragments?

I have written code for all activities and java files but I don't know that sliding menu has fragmented and now I have to write all the code fragments.

Comment: You have to use **FragmentTransaction** for that.

Comment: can't i use activity instead of fragments

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826585/android-fragment-move-from-one-view-to-another and http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html see

Answer (score 3):

It's simple Only three line code...

```
Fragment fragment = new SalesFragment();

FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
```

Comment: Hi, What is frame_container?

Answer (score 2):

This is the code I use to switch fragments inside a view:

```
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace([viewId], fragment, tag);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(tag);
fragmentTransaction.setTransition(FragmentTransaction.TRANSIT_FRAGMENT_OPEN);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: what is viewid here ?? what should i write in place of that?

Comment: how can i get fragmentid

Comment: please tell me i am new to fragment

Comment: No..Its a layout. R.id.urFrgId. Something like this

Comment: It's the view that's gonna hold the fragment. The fragment will be inserted inside this view. Read the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace(int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String)).

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also:-

> ```
> public void ButtonClick(View view) {
>   Fragment mFragment = new YourNextFragment(); 
>  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
>             .replace(R.id.content_frame, mFragment ).commit();
>  }
> ```

Answer (score 0):

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager
                        .beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.frame_container,
                                new TeacherFragment()).commit();
```

Comment: This is just equivalent to [this existing answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20784516/how-to-move-from-one-fragment-to-another-fragment-on-button-click/26337764#26337764).

Answer (score 0):

```
 //Below is the example 

 //In first Fragment 

Fragment fragment = new YourFragmentClassName();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();                       android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft= fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.flContent, fragment);
Bundle args = new Bundle();
// Pass the values what you want to send to next fragment 
args.putInt("Year", rYear);
args.putString("Month", rMonth);
args.putInt("Industry", rIndustry);
fragment.setArguments(args);
ft.commit();

//In Second Fragment

//In onCreateView Method get the values



int strYear= getArguments().getInt("Year");
String strMonth = getArguments().getString("Month");
strIndustry= getArguments().getInt("Industry");

//That's it very simple
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 FragmentTransaction fragmenttransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
 FirstFragment regcomplainfragment = new FirstFragment();
 fragmenttransaction.replace(R.id.content_frame,   regcomplainfragment).addToBackStack("tag");
 fragmenttransaction.commit();
```