# How to prevent creating 2 instances of same fragment?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, fragmentmanager

I have an activity (MainActivity) that contains MasterFragment which contains a viewpager with FragmentA and FragmentB in portrait screen orientation.

In landscape mode the viewpager contains only FragmentA on left side of a split screen, with FragmentB on the right side.

So basically FragmentB is moved to the right of the viewpager in landscape mode.

**Although FragmentB is only shown once in each rotation, two instances are created at the same time after rotation.**

The problem is that FragmentB is in reality a map, and I need to prevent 2 instances to be created at the same time. I need the first instance to be destroyed before the next instance is created.

What happens is the FragmentStateManager recreates FragmentB when calling setContentView in MainActivity.

How do I prevent that?

One solution would be to use super.onCreate(null) in MainActivity, but that is clearly an overkill.

How can I prevent recreating fragments in ViewPager2?

Another solution would be to use the recreated fragment instance and move it from the viewpager to the framlayout and vice versa. How can I move it?

**MasterFragment.java**

```
public class MasterFragment extends Fragment
{
    NewPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager2 mViewPager;
    boolean mSplitView;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.masterfragment, container, false);

        if (isLandScape())
        {
            mSplitView = true;
            getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, new FragmentB(), FragmentB.TAG).commit();
        }
        else if (isLandScape())
        {
            LinearLayout masterlayout = view.findViewById(R.id.masterlayout);
            masterlayout.removeViewAt(1);
        }

        mViewPager = view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new NewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager(), getLifecycle());

        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(7);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        return view;
    }

    public boolean isLandScape()
    {
        int orientation = getResources().getConfiguration().orientation;
        return orientation == Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE;
    }

    public boolean backOnePage()
    {
        if(mViewPager == null)
            return false;

        int page = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();

        if(page > 0)
        {
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(page - 1);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public void viewFragmentB()
    {
        if(!mSplitView)
            mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
    }

    public class NewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStateAdapter
    {
        public NewPagerAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fragmentManager, @NonNull Lifecycle lifecycle)
        {
            super(fragmentManager, lifecycle);
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public Fragment createFragment(int position)
        {
            if(position == 0)
                return new FragmentA();

            return new FragmentB();
        }

        @Override
        public int getItemCount()
        {
            return mSplitView ? 1 : 2;
        }
    }
}
```

**masterfragment.xml (Portrait)**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#ff000000"
        android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1.0"
    />
        
</LinearLayout>
```

**masterfragment.xml (Landscape)**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/masterlayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:background="#ff000000">

    <androidx.viewpager2.widget.ViewPager2
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
    />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
{
    MasterFragment mMasterFragment;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Fragment fragment = savedInstanceState != null
                ? getSupportFragmentManager().getFragment(savedInstanceState, "MasterFragment")
                : null;

        mMasterFragment = fragment instanceof MasterFragment
                ? (MasterFragment)fragment
                : (MasterFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.masterfragment);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() 
    {
        if(mMasterFragment != null && mMasterFragment.backOnePage())
            return;

        super.finish();
    }
}
```

**FragmentA**

```
public class FragmentA extends Fragment
{   
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);

        view.findViewById(R.id.title).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view)
            {
                MasterFragment.getInstance().viewFragmentB();
            }
        });

        return view;
    }
}
```

**FragmentB**

```
public class FragmentB extends Fragment
{
    public static String TAG = "OrderFragment";
    static int COUNTER;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_crew, container, false);

        COUNTER++; // COUNTER BECOMES 2

        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        COUNTER--;

        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

**main.xml**

```
<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:name="com.mobile.MasterFragment"
    android:id="@+id/masterfragment"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Comment: can you share the main layout as well?

Comment: I have added main.xml

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `setRetainInstance` in fragment that you want to retain over Activity configuration change.

[Source](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment#setRetainInstance(boolean))

*Edit*

Thanks @martin for pointing that `setRetainInstance` is deprecated.

The requirement to prevent fragment recreation over configuration change is unachievable as per my understanding. I would suggest to maintain the fragment state via view model instance as per [Android Doc's](https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1159084/) suggestion

Comment: `setRetainInstance` has been marked as deprecated, this is not a good idea. (Deprecated in API level 28)

Comment: setRetainInstance has been deprecated. I am not trying to retain the same instance, but trying to prevent creating 2 instances at the same time (onCreateView is called 2 times without onDestroy in between)

Comment: FragmentA is only created once at a time, although it appears in both portrait and landscape in the viewpager.

Comment: Reason is, during landscape rotation you are adding a new FragmentB instance in FrameLayout container to show it. At the same time your MasterFragment is recreated again implicitly invoking FragmentB twice.

Comment: How can I prevent recreation of a given fragment or fragment instance?

Comment: Similar question here, but I just want to prevent automatic recreation of a specific fragment
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15519214/prevent-fragment-recovery-in-android

Comment: I'm afraid we cannot prevent recreation of a certain fragment. I'd rather save the Fragment state in viewmodel instance and restore it upon recreation. I agree with @Martin + This https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/1159084/

Comment: The problem is not the state (there is no state), but creating 2 instances of this fragment causes problem. I need to prevent that.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that you're always doing `new FragmentB()` or `new Fragment...()` instead of checking if it's already in the fragmentManager.

You have to do something like (please excuse my *kotlin pseudocode*)

```
var fragmentB = fragmentManager.findFragmentByTag("FragB")

if fragmentB == null { 
   fragmentB = // create new instance
} 

fragmentManager.replace(..., fragmentB, "FragB") //use the same tag you'll use later to search for it
```

Comment: the 'FragmentStateAdapter' used by the ViewPager adds FragmentB to FragmentManager with tag "f0", "f1",, based on its position in the viewpager. I tried to find that instance when rotating to landscape and use that instead of new instance, but it the fragment does appear (the right half pane is black).

Comment: I mean "does not appear"

Comment: I would think the solution would be rather to remove fragment from fragmentmanager before another instance is created

Comment: It's been a while since I used a VPager w/those adapters, so is there no way to override the Tag?

Comment: That would be very hacky. I think it is not possible to reuse the fragment, I would rather like to make sure the FragmentStateManager won't recreate FragmentB

Answer (score 0):

Seems I need to answer my own question.

As some mentioned this is not directly supported by the Android platform.

Some possibilities are:

1. super.onCreate(null) in MainActivity (which will disable all state restore)
2. Write custom viewpager/adapter that omit the fragment in saving state (a lot of work)
3. After rotation, move fragment from/to Viewpager to/from Framelayout, but this will require customer viewpager/adapter that allows removing fragment view without destroying it (see moving view [Android Fragment - move from one View to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15826585/android-fragment-move-from-one-view-to-another)), which is presumably a lot of work